# How to check how much a given library weighs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd, react-bootstrap

How to check how much a given library weighs? I want to compare react bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/), and design (https://ant.design/) and react material ui (https://material-ui.com/ components / transfer-list /).

Comment: Before or after minified?

Comment: @Vencovsky  Installs via nmp and imports to file. Next `nmp run build`.

Comment: A simple way is go to `node_modules`, go in the library folder and check it's size

Comment: With https://bundlephobia.com/